# Adding existing .h and .c files to a Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header-files

I would like to use some pre-written .h and .c files in my MSVS2010 C++ project.
These are source files of a library that I would like to use in my project.
I went and added .h files to "Header Files" folder in my MSVS solution, and .c files to "Source Files" folder.
But when I include one of the .h files using include "sample.h", it does not recognize that header file.
What do I need to do so that MSVS recognize the added files?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the path to the header to the `Extra include directories` in the project settings.

Adding existing files to a project doesn't actually copy the files. They remain in their original location.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I do this in MSVS2010?

Comment: @TJ1 right click on the project -> properties -> configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Additional include directories